# Convert text to number in Excel in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason Excel is converting my number into text and adding a preceding apostrophe in every cell in column E3 and F3.

I need to convert columns E3:F3 back to numbers and format them to currency. How do I do that?

A1:K2 is the header.

The code below is not working:

```
Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("aFile.xls", True, False)
wb.Sheets(1).Rows(2).Delete
wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3") = Mid(wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3"), 2,
                              Len(wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3")) - 2)
wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the same currency formatting you get from the toolbar, this works:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3").Formula = wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3").Value
wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3").Style = "Currency"
```

Just using `worksheet.Range()` with no properties forces Excel to guess exactly which property you actually mean (this is called the "default property"), and you get inconsistent results.

Comment: Nice. It did work. How do you get the entire column to be formatted that way except E1,E2,F1,F2 (which is the header of the column)? Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably have to do something like `Range("E:F").Style = "Currency"` followed by fixing the headers: `Range("E1:F2").Style = "Normal"`

Comment: This seemed to have worked:`wb.Sheets(1).Range("E:F").Formula = wb.Sheets(1).Range("E:F").Value
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("E:F").Style = "Currency"`

Answer (score 2):

**If your text is only a number**, the answer is simple. Multiply it by 1.
Say cell A1= '00001234 or a formula or macro returns a piece of text, multiply  the answer by 1.
**"00001234" * 1 = 1234.**
I want to extract the value of a Label or a txtBox on a VBA form.
**Num = lblText * 1**
Another example:
**If .txtLevel10 * 1 > 50 Then**...etc.
Also works with some other data types  **"16-Jan-15" *1 = 16/1/15**
Works in Excel & VBA but only if there are no other characters in the original text.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Range("E3:F3").Style = "Currency"
```

Comment: Did not work but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try highlighting that column and doing Data->Text To Columns (Excel 2003; in 2007+ Text to columns is on one of the ribbons). Click 'Delimited', then 'Next', Next again, then select General as the format. This should convert the whole column into a number.

If this works, it is easily automated. Let me know if you need code.

EDIT - you have to do one column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This, actually, works. The key is to apply format *before* setting the value:

```
Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("aFile.xls", True, False)
wb.Sheets(1).Rows(2).Delete

wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

For Row = 3 To 3 'your rows range in case you need iterate through (1 row only in your case)
    For Column = 5 To 6 'E3:F3
        wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, Column) = Mid(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, Column), 2, Len(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Row, Column)) - 2)
    Next Column
Next Row
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Len(wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3"))
```

For me this just (as expected) throws an error.  You'll have to process each cell individually to use your approach.

```
Dim c as Range
Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("aFile.xls", True, False)    

With wb.Sheets(1)
   .Rows(2).Delete    
   For each c in .Range("E3:F3").cells
     c.Value = Mid(c.value, 2, Len(c.value)-2) 
     c.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
   next c
End With
```